# Google gdata api for iphone, how to save login credentials (username and password) or session?

Tags: iphone, security, google-api, youtube-api, gdata

Using [GData](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client/), is there a built in way to store a session or credentials for interacting with the gdata api, or do I need to store credentials manually in the keychain? I'm using the YouTube upload API, and want to ensure the user doesn't have to enter username and pw each time. If there's a way to automatically get the user's Google login session, that's even better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The GTM OAuth is newer, but the GData API's also support this via the setAuthorizer method. I didn't notice that until I dove into the source code.

```
//save to keychain
- (void)viewController:(GDataOAuthViewControllerTouch *)viewController
      finishedWithAuth:(GDataOAuthAuthentication *)auth
                 error:(NSError *)error {
if (error != nil) {
        // Authentication failed

    } else {
        [[self youTubeService] setAuthorizer:auth];
    }
}

//check if authorized:
- (BOOL)isAuthorized
{
   GDataOAuthAuthentication * auth = [GDataOAuthViewControllerTouch authForGoogleFromKeychainForName:kAppServiceName];
   BOOL isSignedIn = [auth canAuthorize]; // returns NO if auth cannot authorize requests
   if(isSignedIn) [[self youTubeService] setAuthorizer:auth];
   return isSignedIn;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the GTM Oauth library (http://code.google.com/p/gtm-oauth/), they provide a method to store access token information in keychain by service name (e.g. "YouTubeAPI" or something).

Additionally, if you're using raw username / password, I would definitely store the details in keychain. Sci-Fi Hi-Fi has a nice, easy to use library that I've used in the past - http://github.com/ldandersen/scifihifi-iphone.

Comment: I'm using the stuff at http://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client. GTM looks like it will work with this. I'll give it a try, thanks.